# When I upgrade my React native project to version 0.69.0 I got this type of error

Tags: android, react-native, patch, react-native-reanimated

After upgrading my react native project to version 0.69.0, I am getting this error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yarn add react-native-reanimated@next` will upgrade you to the patched version

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming because of react-native-reanimation.

I used a patch that worked for me. Attaching the git link of the patch.

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3320#issuecomment-1166586113

Comment: how to use this patch

Comment: if you look at the patch they have mentioned the path in which file you need to change. there you need to replace red lines with green lines

Comment: use the patch-package module. you basically create a /patches folder and put the git diff in there, then post install it will apply the diff to the package installed in node_modules.